# How to install Apache module

Tags: apache, whm

I'm using Apache 2.2.23 and I'm trying to install mod_authz_host module located here:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html

When I run Easy Apache in WHM, this module isn't located in the Exhaustive options list. Is there a way I can install this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The way EasyApache compiles Apache, mod_rewrite functionality is compiled directly into Apache and will not appear on a list of modules loaded on Apache. If you're running cPanel/WHM, you have mod_rewrite functionality in Apache